# Bison Shift/reduce error for C-like language

Tags: bison, reduce, shift

I'm having an issue with my bison grammar, it is giving me shift/reduce errors, and I have already defined precedence for the operators.

I know that it is cause by the 'expr binop expr' bit of the expr rule.  Here is my bison file, and the output I get.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
%token ID KEYWORD INTCON FLOATCON TYPE STRING
%token IF WHILE FOR VOID RETURN
%token AND_OP OR_OP EQ_OP NEQ_OP LEQ_OP GEQ_OP

%left OR_OP
%left AND_OP
%nonassoc '<' LEQ_OP '>' GEQ_OP EQ_OP NEQ_OP
%left '+' '-'
%left '/' '*'
%right '!'
%%


expr      : unop expr
          | expr binop expr
          | ID
          | ID '[' expr ']'
          | ID '(' expr_list ')'
          | ID '(' ')'
          | '(' expr ')'
          | INTCON
          | FLOATCON
          ;

expr_list : expr
          | expr_list ',' expr
          ;

unop      : '!' ;

binop     : AND_OP | OR_OP | EQ_OP | NEQ_OP | '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | LEQ_OP | '<' | GEQ_OP | '>' ;
```

And the output file:

```
Terminals unused in grammar

   KEYWORD
   TYPE
   STRING
   IF
   WHILE
   FOR
   VOID
   RETURN


State 25 conflicts: 12 shift/reduce
State 31 conflicts: 12 shift/reduce


Grammar

    0 $accept: expr $end

    1 expr: unop expr
    2     | expr binop expr
    3     | ID
    4     | ID '[' expr ']'
    5     | ID '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | ID '(' ')'
    7     | '(' expr ')'
    8     | INTCON
    9     | FLOATCON

   10 expr_list: expr
   11          | expr_list ',' expr

   12 unop: '!'

   13 binop: AND_OP
   14      | OR_OP
   15      | EQ_OP
   16      | NEQ_OP
   17      | '+'
   18      | '-'
   19      | '*'
   20      | '/'
   21      | LEQ_OP
   22      | '<'
   23      | GEQ_OP
   24      | '>'


Terminals, with rules where they appear

$end (0) 0
'!' (33) 12
'(' (40) 5 6 7
')' (41) 5 6 7
'*' (42) 19
'+' (43) 17
',' (44) 11
'-' (45) 18
'/' (47) 20
'<' (60) 22
'>' (62) 24
'[' (91) 4
']' (93) 4
error (256)
ID (258) 3 4 5 6
KEYWORD (259)
INTCON (260) 8
FLOATCON (261) 9
TYPE (262)
STRING (263)
IF (264)
WHILE (265)
FOR (266)
VOID (267)
RETURN (268)
AND_OP (269) 13
OR_OP (270) 14
EQ_OP (271) 15
NEQ_OP (272) 16
LEQ_OP (273) 21
GEQ_OP (274) 23


Nonterminals, with rules where they appear

$accept (32)
    on left: 0
expr (33)
    on left: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9, on right: 0 1 2 4 7 10 11
expr_list (34)
    on left: 10 11, on right: 5 11
unop (35)
    on left: 12, on right: 1
binop (36)
    on left: 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24, on right: 2


state 0

    0 $accept: . expr $end
    1 expr: . unop expr
    2     | . expr binop expr
    3     | . ID
    4     | . ID '[' expr ']'
    5     | . ID '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | . ID '(' ')'
    7     | . '(' expr ')'
    8     | . INTCON
    9     | . FLOATCON
   12 unop: . '!'

    ID        shift, and go to state 1
    INTCON    shift, and go to state 2
    FLOATCON  shift, and go to state 3
    '!'       shift, and go to state 4
    '('       shift, and go to state 5

    expr  go to state 6
    unop  go to state 7


state 1

    3 expr: ID .  [$end, AND_OP, OR_OP, EQ_OP, NEQ_OP, LEQ_OP, GEQ_OP, '<', '>', '+', '-', '/', '*', ']', ')', ',']
    4     | ID . '[' expr ']'
    5     | ID . '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | ID . '(' ')'

    '('  shift, and go to state 8
    '['  shift, and go to state 9

    $default  reduce using rule 3 (expr)


state 2

    8 expr: INTCON .

    $default  reduce using rule 8 (expr)


state 3

    9 expr: FLOATCON .

    $default  reduce using rule 9 (expr)


state 4

   12 unop: '!' .

    $default  reduce using rule 12 (unop)


state 5

    1 expr: . unop expr
    2     | . expr binop expr
    3     | . ID
    4     | . ID '[' expr ']'
    5     | . ID '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | . ID '(' ')'
    7     | . '(' expr ')'
    7     | '(' . expr ')'
    8     | . INTCON
    9     | . FLOATCON
   12 unop: . '!'

    ID        shift, and go to state 1
    INTCON    shift, and go to state 2
    FLOATCON  shift, and go to state 3
    '!'       shift, and go to state 4
    '('       shift, and go to state 5

    expr  go to state 10
    unop  go to state 7


state 6

    0 $accept: expr . $end
    2 expr: expr . binop expr
   13 binop: . AND_OP
   14      | . OR_OP
   15      | . EQ_OP
   16      | . NEQ_OP
   17      | . '+'
   18      | . '-'
   19      | . '*'
   20      | . '/'
   21      | . LEQ_OP
   22      | . '<'
   23      | . GEQ_OP
   24      | . '>'

    $end    shift, and go to state 11
    AND_OP  shift, and go to state 12
    OR_OP   shift, and go to state 13
    EQ_OP   shift, and go to state 14
    NEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 15
    LEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 16
    GEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 17
    '<'     shift, and go to state 18
    '>'     shift, and go to state 19
    '+'     shift, and go to state 20
    '-'     shift, and go to state 21
    '/'     shift, and go to state 22
    '*'     shift, and go to state 23

    binop  go to state 24


state 7

    1 expr: . unop expr
    1     | unop . expr
    2     | . expr binop expr
    3     | . ID
    4     | . ID '[' expr ']'
    5     | . ID '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | . ID '(' ')'
    7     | . '(' expr ')'
    8     | . INTCON
    9     | . FLOATCON
   12 unop: . '!'

    ID        shift, and go to state 1
    INTCON    shift, and go to state 2
    FLOATCON  shift, and go to state 3
    '!'       shift, and go to state 4
    '('       shift, and go to state 5

    expr  go to state 25
    unop  go to state 7


state 8

    1 expr: . unop expr
    2     | . expr binop expr
    3     | . ID
    4     | . ID '[' expr ']'
    5     | . ID '(' expr_list ')'
    5     | ID '(' . expr_list ')'
    6     | . ID '(' ')'
    6     | ID '(' . ')'
    7     | . '(' expr ')'
    8     | . INTCON
    9     | . FLOATCON
   10 expr_list: . expr
   11          | . expr_list ',' expr
   12 unop: . '!'

    ID        shift, and go to state 1
    INTCON    shift, and go to state 2
    FLOATCON  shift, and go to state 3
    '!'       shift, and go to state 4
    '('       shift, and go to state 5
    ')'       shift, and go to state 26

    expr       go to state 27
    expr_list  go to state 28
    unop       go to state 7


state 9

    1 expr: . unop expr
    2     | . expr binop expr
    3     | . ID
    4     | . ID '[' expr ']'
    4     | ID '[' . expr ']'
    5     | . ID '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | . ID '(' ')'
    7     | . '(' expr ')'
    8     | . INTCON
    9     | . FLOATCON
   12 unop: . '!'

    ID        shift, and go to state 1
    INTCON    shift, and go to state 2
    FLOATCON  shift, and go to state 3
    '!'       shift, and go to state 4
    '('       shift, and go to state 5

    expr  go to state 29
    unop  go to state 7


state 10

    2 expr: expr . binop expr
    7     | '(' expr . ')'
   13 binop: . AND_OP
   14      | . OR_OP
   15      | . EQ_OP
   16      | . NEQ_OP
   17      | . '+'
   18      | . '-'
   19      | . '*'
   20      | . '/'
   21      | . LEQ_OP
   22      | . '<'
   23      | . GEQ_OP
   24      | . '>'

    AND_OP  shift, and go to state 12
    OR_OP   shift, and go to state 13
    EQ_OP   shift, and go to state 14
    NEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 15
    LEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 16
    GEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 17
    '<'     shift, and go to state 18
    '>'     shift, and go to state 19
    '+'     shift, and go to state 20
    '-'     shift, and go to state 21
    '/'     shift, and go to state 22
    '*'     shift, and go to state 23
    ')'     shift, and go to state 30

    binop  go to state 24


state 11

    0 $accept: expr $end .

    $default  accept


state 12

   13 binop: AND_OP .

    $default  reduce using rule 13 (binop)


state 13

   14 binop: OR_OP .

    $default  reduce using rule 14 (binop)


state 14

   15 binop: EQ_OP .

   $default  reduce using rule 15 (binop)


state 15

   16 binop: NEQ_OP .

    $default  reduce using rule 16 (binop)


state 16

   21 binop: LEQ_OP .

    $default  reduce using rule 21 (binop)


state 17

   23 binop: GEQ_OP .

    $default  reduce using rule 23 (binop)


state 18

   22 binop: '<' .

    $default  reduce using rule 22 (binop)


state 19

   24 binop: '>' .

    $default  reduce using rule 24 (binop)


state 20

   17 binop: '+' .

    $default  reduce using rule 17 (binop)


state 21

   18 binop: '-' .

    $default  reduce using rule 18 (binop)


state 22

   20 binop: '/' .

    $default  reduce using rule 20 (binop)


state 23

   19 binop: '*' .

    $default  reduce using rule 19 (binop)


state 24

    1 expr: . unop expr
    2     | . expr binop expr
   2     | expr binop . expr
    3     | . ID
    4     | . ID '[' expr ']'
    5     | . ID '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | . ID '(' ')'
    7     | . '(' expr ')'
    8     | . INTCON
    9     | . FLOATCON
   12 unop: . '!'

    ID        shift, and go to state 1
    INTCON    shift, and go to state 2
    FLOATCON  shift, and go to state 3
    '!'       shift, and go to state 4
    '('       shift, and go to state 5

    expr  go to state 31
    unop  go to state 7


state 25

    1 expr: unop expr .  [$end, AND_OP, OR_OP, EQ_OP, NEQ_OP, LEQ_OP, GEQ_OP, '<', '>', '+', '-', '/', '*', ']', ')', ',']
    2     | expr . binop expr
   13 binop: . AND_OP
   14      | . OR_OP
   15      | . EQ_OP
   16      | . NEQ_OP
   17      | . '+'
   18      | . '-'
   19      | . '*'
   20      | . '/'
   21      | . LEQ_OP
   22      | . '<'
   23      | . GEQ_OP
   24      | . '>'

    AND_OP  shift, and go to state 12
    OR_OP   shift, and go to state 13
    EQ_OP   shift, and go to state 14
    NEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 15
    LEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 16
    GEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 17
    '<'     shift, and go to state 18
    '>'     shift, and go to state 19
    '+'     shift, and go to state 20
    '-'     shift, and go to state 21
    '/'     shift, and go to state 22
    '*'     shift, and go to state 23

    AND_OP    [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    OR_OP     [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    EQ_OP     [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    NEQ_OP    [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    LEQ_OP    [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    GEQ_OP    [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    '<'       [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    '>'       [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    '+'       [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    '-'       [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    '/'       [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    '*'       [reduce using rule 1 (expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 1 (expr)

    binop  go to state 24


state 26

    6 expr: ID '(' ')' .
   $default  reduce using rule 6 (expr)


state 27

    2 expr: expr . binop expr
   10 expr_list: expr .  [')', ',']
   13 binop: . AND_OP
   14      | . OR_OP
   15      | . EQ_OP
   16      | . NEQ_OP
   17      | . '+'
   18      | . '-'
   19      | . '*'
   20      | . '/'
   21      | . LEQ_OP
   22      | . '<'
   23      | . GEQ_OP
   24      | . '>'

    AND_OP  shift, and go to state 12
    OR_OP   shift, and go to state 13
    EQ_OP   shift, and go to state 14
    NEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 15
    LEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 16
    GEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 17
    '<'     shift, and go to state 18
    '>'     shift, and go to state 19
    '+'     shift, and go to state 20
    '-'     shift, and go to state 21
    '/'     shift, and go to state 22
    '*'     shift, and go to state 23

    $default  reduce using rule 10 (expr_list)

    binop  go to state 24


state 28

    5 expr: ID '(' expr_list . ')'
   11 expr_list: expr_list . ',' expr

    ')'  shift, and go to state 32
    ','  shift, and go to state 33


state 29

    2 expr: expr . binop expr
    4     | ID '[' expr . ']'
   13 binop: . AND_OP
   14      | . OR_OP
   15      | . EQ_OP
   16      | . NEQ_OP
   17      | . '+'
   18      | . '-'
   19      | . '*'
   20      | . '/'
   21      | . LEQ_OP
   22      | . '<'
   23      | . GEQ_OP
   24      | . '>'

    AND_OP  shift, and go to state 12
    OR_OP   shift, and go to state 13
    EQ_OP   shift, and go to state 14
    NEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 15
    LEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 16
    GEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 17
    '<'     shift, and go to state 18
    '>'     shift, and go to state 19
    '+'     shift, and go to state 20
    '-'     shift, and go to state 21
    '/'     shift, and go to state 22
    '*'     shift, and go to state 23
    ']'     shift, and go to state 34

    binop  go to state 24


state 30

    7 expr: '(' expr ')' .

    $default  reduce using rule 7 (expr)


state 31

    2 expr: expr . binop expr
    2     | expr binop expr .  [$end, AND_OP, OR_OP, EQ_OP, NEQ_OP, LEQ_OP, GEQ_OP, '<', '>', '+', '-', '/', '*', ']', ')', ',']
   13 binop: . AND_OP
   14      | . OR_OP
   15      | . EQ_OP
   16      | . NEQ_OP
   17      | . '+'
   18      | . '-'
   19      | . '*'
   20      | . '/'
   21      | . LEQ_OP
   22      | . '<'
   23      | . GEQ_OP
   24      | . '>'

    AND_OP  shift, and go to state 12
    OR_OP   shift, and go to state 13
    EQ_OP   shift, and go to state 14
    NEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 15
    LEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 16
    GEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 17
    '<'     shift, and go to state 18
    '>'     shift, and go to state 19
    '+'     shift, and go to state 20
    '-'     shift, and go to state 21
    '/'     shift, and go to state 22
    '*'     shift, and go to state 23

    AND_OP    [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    OR_OP     [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    EQ_OP     [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    NEQ_OP    [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    LEQ_OP    [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    GEQ_OP    [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    '<'       [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    '>'       [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    '+'       [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    '-'       [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    '/'       [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    '*'       [reduce using rule 2 (expr)]
    $default  reduce using rule 2 (expr)

    binop  go to state 24


state 32

    5 expr: ID '(' expr_list ')' .

    5 expr: ID '(' expr_list ')' .

    $default  reduce using rule 5 (expr)


state 33

    1 expr: . unop expr
    2     | . expr binop expr
    3     | . ID
    4     | . ID '[' expr ']'
    5     | . ID '(' expr_list ')'
    6     | . ID '(' ')'
    7     | . '(' expr ')'
    8     | . INTCON
    9     | . FLOATCON
   11 expr_list: expr_list ',' . expr
   12 unop: . '!'

    ID        shift, and go to state 1
    INTCON    shift, and go to state 2
    FLOATCON  shift, and go to state 3
    '!'       shift, and go to state 4
    '('       shift, and go to state 5

    expr  go to state 35
    unop  go to state 7


state 34

    4 expr: ID '[' expr ']' .

    $default  reduce using rule 4 (expr)


state 35

    2 expr: expr . binop expr
   11 expr_list: expr_list ',' expr .  [')', ',']
   13 binop: . AND_OP
   14      | . OR_OP
   15      | . EQ_OP
   16      | . NEQ_OP
   17      | . '+'
   18      | . '-'
   19      | . '*'
   20      | . '/'
   21      | . LEQ_OP
   22      | . '<'
   23      | . GEQ_OP
   24      | . '>'

    AND_OP  shift, and go to state 12
    OR_OP   shift, and go to state 13
    EQ_OP   shift, and go to state 14
    NEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 15
    LEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 16
    GEQ_OP  shift, and go to state 17
    '<'     shift, and go to state 18
    '>'     shift, and go to state 19
    '+'     shift, and go to state 20
    '-'     shift, and go to state 21
    '/'     shift, and go to state 22
    '*'     shift, and go to state 23

    $default  reduce using rule 11 (expr_list)

    binop  go to state 24
```

## **FIX BY RICI BELOW:**#

(Removed the unop and binop rules and enumerated them in the expr rule)

```
%token ID KEYWORD INTCON FLOATCON TYPE STRING
%token IF WHILE FOR VOID RETURN
%token AND_OP OR_OP EQ_OP NEQ_OP LEQ_OP GEQ_OP

%left "||"
%left "&&"
%nonassoc '<' "<=" '>' ">=" "==" "!="
%left '+' '-'
%left '/' '*'
%right '!'
%%    

expr      : ID
          | ID '[' expr ']'
          | ID '(' expr_list ')'
          | ID '(' ')'
          | '(' expr ')'
          | INTCON
          | FLOATCON
          | '!'  expr
          | '-' expr
          | expr '+' expr
          | expr '-' expr
          | expr '/' expr
          | expr '*' expr
          | expr '<' expr
          | expr '>' expr
          | expr "<=" expr
          | expr ">=" expr
          | expr "==" expr
          | expr "!=" expr
          | expr "&&" expr
          | expr "||" expr
          ;

expr_list : expr
          | expr_list ',' expr
          ;
%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence only works if the productions directly include terminals named in the precedence declaration.

In other words, you cannot use `expr: expr binop expr` because the precedence relations can't help bison decide whether to shift the reduced `binop` non-terminal or reduce the `expr` on the top of the parse stack. Bison would have to know what the terminal inside the `binop` was, but it doesn't know that any more. (That's why reductions are called "reductions".)

To make it work, you have to write the productions out in full:

```
expr: expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    | expr '*' expr
    |...
```